# ADF can't properly recognize JSON columns while pushing to Cosmos

Tags: json, azure-data-factory, azure-cosmosdb

The source of the ADF Pipeline is a query. Something along the lines of this.

```
SELECT
   FirstName,
   LastName,
   (
        SELECT Phonenumber FROM Phones p WHERE p.PhoneID = a.PhoneID
        FOR JSON PATH
    ) as PhoneNumbers
FROM Accounts a
FOR JSON PATH
```

It all looks like valid JSON however. No matter what I do I can't get ADF to recognize it as JSON. It sees it as a string and when sending to Parquet or Cosmos it invalidates the JSON by adding escape characters like `[{\\"FirstName\\":\\"TheDude\\"...`

I need to be able to read the data that has JSON in it and write it out to Cosmos while keeping the JSON intact. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tried to output the column Phone Numbers to Cosmos and expected it to look like regular JSON output, instead it has escape characters around the quotes.

Comment: Can you provide your sample input and expected output? and pipeline image for better understanding?

Comment: In the most simplest explanation  [{"FirstName":"TheDude" becomes  [{\"FirstName\":\"TheDude\" because it thinks the JSON is text not JSON. and is outputting it as text hence the escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

The above query will generate the JSON,  but in ADF it will take it as string because it is taking it as the row value. And that is the reason it is copying that row as it is to the target.

> I need to be able to read the data that has JSON in it and write it out to Cosmos while keeping the JSON intact.

To achieve this, first you need to store the generated JSON and then copy that JSON to cosmos db. For this you need to 2 copy data activities.

**Copy data activity to store the JSON in blob:**

Give your query in copy activity source. Here, I have given a sample query.

[image]

To store the JSON string as JSON file, use the **delimited text dataset as sink in this copy activity with `.json`  file extension** and give the following configurations.

[image]

Leave the mapping of the copy activity as it is.

You will get the JSON file like below after 1st copy activity execution.

[image]

**Copy data activity for JSON to Cosmos db:**

Now, create a JSON dataset for the above in ADF and use it as the source for the 2nd copy activity. In sink give your Cosmos db dataset.

Follow the below mapping.

[image]

Now, you will get the JSON from query in Cosmos db after the execution of above.

[image]

**My Pipeline JSON for your reference:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy data from SQL to JSON",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "sqlReaderQuery": "SELECT\n   FirstName,\n   LastName,\n   (\n        SELECT Phonenumber FROM s1\n        FOR JSON PATH\n    ) as PhoneNumbers\nFROM s1\nFOR JSON PATH;",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".txt"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "typeConversion": true,
                        "typeConversionSettings": {
                            "allowDataTruncation": true,
                            "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "jsoncsv",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Copy data from JSON to cosmos",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Copy data from SQL to JSON",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "JsonSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "JsonReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "CosmosDbSqlApiSink",
                        "writeBehavior": "insert",
                        "disableMetricsCollection": false
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false,
                    "translator": {
                        "type": "TabularTranslator",
                        "mappings": [
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['FirstName']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "path": "FirstName"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['LastName']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "path": "LastName"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "source": {
                                    "path": "$['PhoneNumbers']"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "path": "PhoneNumbers"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "collectionReference": ""
                    }
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "Json1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "CosmosDbNoSqlContainer1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```